# Drools integrated in a web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, drools

I'm just new with drools and web development, I'm just wondering if how can i integrate `Drools` in a `Web Application`, I'm using `JSP` and `Servlet` technology if I'm not mistaken with the term. I'm also planning of using `MVC` pattern not `SpringMVC`.

What I already done is:

1. Downloaded `Drools` and `jBPM` as plug-in in eclipse ( Able to create a Drools Project as a proof)
2. Already create a Dynamic Web Project, running and using Tomcat as a server

**My question is where should i put Drool library for me to use the rules depends on the user's input in a JSP? Or if i missing something kindly tell me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, libraries (jar files) should be put in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application, which can then be packaged as a whole in a .war file. Tomcat (or whichever servlet container you decide to use) will then load them in the classpath as part of its webapp initialisation. Drools might require specific configuration to tell it where it will find the rule files to load them, check the Drools documentation for that.

I can assure you it works from within a web app and also within an application using the Spring framework. I've seen it work with web services using JAX-WS (Apache CXF) with Spring on Tomcat exposing web services which use Drools to determine what business logic to apply.

Comment: I looked at the documentation of Drools as you said. Maybe the configuration you are talking about is the `pom.xml` which is just for Spring. Since I'm not going to use Spring that also mean the i have no `pom.xml` can you guide me a bit more to this. I really don't know what should i do. And also i put the jars at the `WEB-INF/lib` the jars that Drools uses

Comment: `pom.xml` is for [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)(a build tool used in the example) and is not related to Spring in any way, although the examples might use Spring as well.

Comment: @user2771955 pom.xml is for Maven, not for Spring. All it is doing is managing the project's dependencies (instead of manually adding them yourself). You can see the pom.xml file as the project file IntelliJ / Eclipse / Netbeans create, just that it is IDE independent (this is a bit too simplistic, but for you to get the idea). You don't need any configuration, if you just put the jar files in WEB-INF/lib the webapp will find them. (Btw, it might be a good idea in fact to start using Maven, that way it puts all dependencies in place for you and you can follow examples which use it more easily)

Comment: One more question before i accept the answer, Am I right using Drools which this plug-in **"http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/"** I install to eclipse is what I needed to develop an rule-based system?

Comment: @user2771955 sorry didn't get the question. The url is incorrect too. Can you reword?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Does Drools Experts is the one i needed for developing Expert Systems? With These Simple rules `if student has grade < some scope then knowledge level is this` Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Drools Expert is the main Drools Rules Engine that is most popularly used, that supports the Domain Specific Language allowing you to do the rules in the style you are saying. The others are a bit less mature. You might want to look at Guvnor which is a web-based application which allows you to create the rules in a more visual way, although the last time I checked it wasn't quite there yet. Maybe it matured over the past year or so.

Comment: Can you guide me a bit more to this? I can't write a simple rule that printing Hello World in the console. Well that is if you don't mind. I hope.

Comment: Why don't you spend a little time reading this? http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/  Its not something you can grasp quickly with a couple of comments here. You have to sit down understand the concepts a little and try things out slowly.

Comment: Hi,  I would have approx similar requirement. Please check this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151071/how-to-integrate-drools-in-jersey-rest-web-service?noredirect=1#comment28327654_19151071
Thanks